# @RunWith cannot be resolved to a type - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I have a problem testing with Spring Boot. The error seems to happen with JUnit but I have the pom dependency correctly written.

Here is the error:

[image]

The message error is: RunWith cannot be resolved to a type.

And the pom dependency:

[image]

Does anybody know why is this happening? I haven't found similar errors and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

It's already solved.
Open the cmd and go to your project directory, then execute: "mvn dependency:purge-local-repository". This will reinstall your dependencies, because it may be corrupt.

And if you refresh your project it should let you import the @RunWith like this:

[image]

Before the purge I wasn't able to import it.

Answer (score 0):

[`@RunWith` annotation has been replaced by the more powerful `@ExtendWith` annotation.](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith)

[**As of Spring Boot 2.1,**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#junit-5) All `@…​Test` annotations are meta-annotated with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` so this can be **removed** if you’re using JUnit 5.